# Javascript Multiple Value Call

Tags: php, javascript, onclick

I'm calling a function from an input radio button and have this:

```
onClick=\"changeBilling('".$results['id']."', this.value)\"
```

But my this.value isn't working properly. When I look it up in the page, the id is filling properly, but the second value still says this.value, and not the value of the button that is calling the function.

I see this in the browser element manager:

```
onclick="changeBilling('149', this.value)"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Radio Button:

```
<input type='radio' name='billed' value='Yes' onClick=\"changeBilling('".$results['id']."', this.value)\"/> Yes<br /><input type='radio' name='billed' value='No' onClick=\"changebilling('".$results['id']."', this.value)\" checked/> No
```

Ideal Output:

```
onclick="changeBilling('149', 'Yes')"
```

Comment: Can you post the complete HTML for your radio button?

Comment: Try passing "this" alone, debug the object and see if you are getting that properly or not.

Comment: You're using server-side PHP to write the client-side script expression `this.value` as an argument to the client-side function `changeBilling`.  Everything seems to be working as expected.  Would you rather the second argument be a string literal?  Please provide an example of your ideal output.

Comment: Edit your question instead of commenting!

Comment: It's not letting me mark up the content properly. But I tried.

Comment: Have you tried using your browser's JavaScript debugger to step through the changeBilling function?

Comment: By the way, I notice that you're using XHTML style closed tag endings (`/>`) but HTML style valueless `checked` attributed.  If you are in fact outputting XHTML, you should be using `checked="checked"` as all attributes must have values in XML.

Comment: I hard coded values in, but now neither 'checked' nor 'checked="checked"' is setting the initial value. Any ideas about this? Also, has anyone else successfully passed 2 values with one of them being this.value, for a situation where I have a dynamic value?

Comment: The `checked` thing is just about creating valid XHTML; it is an aside that should not affect what you are trying to do at all.  In fact, there is nothing wrong with your HTML.  If the behaviour after clicking on your radio buttons isn't what you expect, then I strongly suspect that it's down to a problem in your `changeBilling` function, not the HTML you have shown here.

Comment: I just somehow lost my form tags somewhere in the process, checked='checked' works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.value` will be evaluate by the client, as its javascrpt, so you will not see the "baked" value in there from your php, you need to check this at runtime, your best bet is to alert the value of `this.value` and check if it is what you  expect, because this is what will be passed to `changeBilling`

```
onClick=\"alert('The value is: '+this.value)\"
```

the issue you may be getting is that `this` may not be evaluating to the thing you expect it to, to find out (if you have a good debugger like Element inspector (chrome) or firebug (firefox)) will be to put:

```
 onClick=\"console.log(this)\"
```

Comment: Runtime shows this: onclick="changeBilling('149', this.value)"

Comment: Aye, and if you put in what in the code above, and run it, the browser should evaluate the script and give you some alerts, I need to know what the runtime offers you, not the output of the PHP.

Comment: The alert comes up with the correct value, "Yes". I'm using Opera's debugger, and I'm not coming up with any javascript errors. I'll just use hard-coded values for now. Thanks for your debugging method.

Comment: no problem, in which case there is probably a bug in your `changeBilling` function, I would have a look in there.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just output the literal value in your PHP:

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='billed' value='Yes' onClick=\"changeBilling('".$results['id']."', 'Yes')\"/> Yes<br /><input type='radio' name='billed' value='No' onClick=\"changebilling('".$results['id']."', 'No')\" checked/> No";
```

**EDIT**

I'm not entirely sure what you're expecting to happen, but there does not appear to be anything wrong with the code you have written.  To demonstrate this point, see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5CDN/) which shows how `this.value` works (note that this has got nothing to do with PHP).

Comment: I could do that in this scenario. That being said, I would like to know if/how I can use the this.value with multiple values being passed for dynamic values.

Comment: Okay, then JavaScript debugging is the way to go, because what you have done *should* work.  If you are using Chrome or Firefox-with-Firebug, this is pretty straightforward.  Simply add a breakpoint at the start of your `changeBilling` function and step through it.  Alternatively, use console.log in your onclick as suggested by Waltzy

Comment: Incidentally, when I say it should work, I mean that your HTML will still say `this.value`, but that gets dereference to the actual value by JavaScript when the `changeBilling` function is called at the onclick event.

Comment: Please see my edited answer above.  I've created a jsFiddle to demonstrate that your code should actually work fine as is.